# Numbering rows within groups in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq, running-count

Working with a data frame similar to this:

```r
set.seed(100)  
df <- data.frame(cat = c(rep("aaa", 5), rep("bbb", 5), rep("ccc", 5)), val = runif(15))             
df <- df[order(df$cat, df$val), ]  
df
```

```
   cat        val  
1  aaa 0.05638315  
2  aaa 0.25767250  
3  aaa 0.30776611  
4  aaa 0.46854928  
5  aaa 0.55232243  
6  bbb 0.17026205  
7  bbb 0.37032054  
8  bbb 0.48377074  
9  bbb 0.54655860  
10 bbb 0.81240262  
11 ccc 0.28035384  
12 ccc 0.39848790  
13 ccc 0.62499648  
14 ccc 0.76255108  
15 ccc 0.88216552
```

I am trying to add a column with numbering within each group. Doing it this way obviously isn't using the powers of R:

```r
 df$num <- 1  
 for (i in 2:(length(df[,1]))) {  
   if (df[i,"cat"]==df[(i-1),"cat"]) {  
     df[i,"num"]<-df[i-1,"num"]+1  
     }  
 }  
 df
```

```
   cat        val num  
1  aaa 0.05638315   1  
2  aaa 0.25767250   2  
3  aaa 0.30776611   3  
4  aaa 0.46854928   4  
5  aaa 0.55232243   5  
6  bbb 0.17026205   1  
7  bbb 0.37032054   2  
8  bbb 0.48377074   3  
9  bbb 0.54655860   4  
10 bbb 0.81240262   5  
11 ccc 0.28035384   1  
12 ccc 0.39848790   2  
13 ccc 0.62499648   3  
14 ccc 0.76255108   4  
15 ccc 0.88216552   5
```

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest to add something like "seq along levels" or "counting along replicates" in the question title as this is how I found this question and it is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @crazysantaclaus If that were the title, I wouldn't have found what I was looking for :-( I was literally looking for "how to number rows within groups in a data frame"

Answer (score 395, accepted):

Use `ave`, `ddply`, `dplyr` or `data.table`:

```
df$num <- ave(df$val, df$cat, FUN = seq_along)
```

or:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(cat), mutate, id = seq_along(val))
```

or:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(cat) %>% mutate(id = row_number())
```

or (the most memory efficient, as it assigns by reference within `DT`):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)

DT[, id := seq_len(.N), by = cat]
DT[, id := rowid(cat)]
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `ave` gives a float instead of an int here. Alternately, could change `df$val` to `seq_len(nrow(df))`. I just ran into this over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796857/r-assign-rank-to-dupicated-ids?noredirect=1#comment72708971_42796857

Comment: Interestingly this `data.table` solution seems to be quicker than using `frank`: 
`library(microbenchmark);
microbenchmark(a = DT[, .(val
                          ,num = frank(val)), by = list(cat)]
               ,b =DT[, .(val
                          , id = seq_len(.N)), by = list(cat)]
               , times = 1000L)`

Comment: Thanks! The `dplyr` solution is good. But if, like me, you kept getting weird errors when trying this approach, make sure that you are not getting conflicts between `plyr` and `dplyr` as explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593791/dplyr-row-number-error-in-rank) It can be avoided by explicitly calling `dplyr::mutate(...)`

Comment: another `data.table` method is `setDT(df)[, id:=rleid(val), by=.(cat)]`

Comment: How to modify `library(plyr)` and `library(dplyr)` answers to make the ranking val column in descending order?

Comment: I tried using the plyr method and got an error: "Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors" - has anyone ever seen that happen?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin You can simply sort the whole dataset in advance. `df <- df[order(df$val),]`

Comment: `data.table` was the moste effective way, it took not a second to compute about 17000 rows. Using `ddply` it was running for ever so I had to kill the R process.

Comment: How could I do if I have some `NA` for the variable `val` and I don't want to consider this rows when creating the variable `num` although I want them to appear in my dataframe with `NA` in the column `num`?

Answer (score 35):

For making this [r-faq](/questions/tagged/r-faq) question more complete, a base R alternative with `sequence` and `rle`:

```
df$num <- sequence(rle(df$cat)$lengths)
```

which gives the intended result:

> ```
> > df
>    cat        val num
> 4  aaa 0.05638315   1
> 2  aaa 0.25767250   2
> 1  aaa 0.30776611   3
> 5  aaa 0.46854928   4
> 3  aaa 0.55232243   5
> 10 bbb 0.17026205   1
> 8  bbb 0.37032054   2
> 6  bbb 0.48377074   3
> 9  bbb 0.54655860   4
> 7  bbb 0.81240262   5
> 13 ccc 0.28035384   1
> 14 ccc 0.39848790   2
> 11 ccc 0.62499648   3
> 15 ccc 0.76255108   4
> 12 ccc 0.88216552   5
> ```

If `df$cat` is a factor variable, you need to wrap it in `as.character` first:

```
df$num <- sequence(rle(as.character(df$cat))$lengths)
```

Comment: Just noticed, this solutions requires `cat` column to be sorted?

Comment: @zx8754 yes, unless you want to number by consecutive occurances of `cat`

Answer (score 14):

Here is a small improvement trick that allows sort 'val' inside the groups:

```
# 1. Data set
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(
  cat = c(rep("aaa", 5), rep("ccc", 5), rep("bbb", 5)), 
  val = runif(15))             

# 2. 'dplyr' approach
df %>% 
  arrange(cat, val) %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())
```

Comment: Can you not sort after the group_by?

Answer (score 12):

Another `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(cat) %>%
 mutate(num = 1:n())

   cat      val   num
   <fct>  <dbl> <int>
 1 aaa   0.0564     1
 2 aaa   0.258      2
 3 aaa   0.308      3
 4 aaa   0.469      4
 5 aaa   0.552      5
 6 bbb   0.170      1
 7 bbb   0.370      2
 8 bbb   0.484      3
 9 bbb   0.547      4
10 bbb   0.812      5
11 ccc   0.280      1
12 ccc   0.398      2
13 ccc   0.625      3
14 ccc   0.763      4
15 ccc   0.882      5
```

Comment: In some cases instead of `1:n()` using `seq_len(n())` is safer, in the event that in your sequence of operations you have a situation where `n()` might return `0`, because `1:0` gives you a length two vector while `seq_len(0)` gives a length zero vector, thus avoiding a length mismatch error with `mutate()`.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to add a `data.table` variant using the `rank()` function which provides the additional possibility to change the ordering and thus makes it a bit more flexible than the `seq_len()` solution and is pretty similar to row_number functions in RDBMS.

```
# Variant with ascending ordering
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, .( val
   , num = rank(val))
    , by = list(cat)][order(cat, num),]

    cat        val num
 1: aaa 0.05638315   1
 2: aaa 0.25767250   2
 3: aaa 0.30776611   3
 4: aaa 0.46854928   4
 5: aaa 0.55232243   5
 6: bbb 0.17026205   1
 7: bbb 0.37032054   2
 8: bbb 0.48377074   3
 9: bbb 0.54655860   4
10: bbb 0.81240262   5
11: ccc 0.28035384   1
12: ccc 0.39848790   2
13: ccc 0.62499648   3
14: ccc 0.76255108   4

# Variant with descending ordering
dt[, .( val
   , num = rank(desc(val)))
    , by = list(cat)][order(cat, num),]
```

Edit on 2021-04-16 to make the switch between descending and ascending order more fail-safe

Answer (score 8):

Here is an option using a `for` loop by groups rather by rows (like OP did)

```
for (i in unique(df$cat)) df$num[df$cat == i] <- seq_len(sum(df$cat == i))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `rowid()` function in `data.table`:

```
> set.seed(100)  
> df <- data.frame(cat = c(rep("aaa", 5), rep("bbb", 5), rep("ccc", 5)), val = runif(15))
> df <- df[order(df$cat, df$val), ]  
> df$num <- data.table::rowid(df$cat)
> df
   cat        val num
4  aaa 0.05638315   1
2  aaa 0.25767250   2
1  aaa 0.30776611   3
5  aaa 0.46854928   4
3  aaa 0.55232243   5
10 bbb 0.17026205   1
8  bbb 0.37032054   2
6  bbb 0.48377074   3
9  bbb 0.54655860   4
7  bbb 0.81240262   5
13 ccc 0.28035384   1
14 ccc 0.39848790   2
11 ccc 0.62499648   3
15 ccc 0.76255108   4
12 ccc 0.88216552   5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems to be already covered in the last suggestion in @mnel's answer

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, tidy solutions.

**Row number for entire data.frame**

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  mutate(row_num = seq_along(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  head

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species row_num
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa       1
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa       2
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa       3
..           ...         ...          ...         ...     ......     ...
148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica     148
149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica     149
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica     150
```

**Row number by group in data.frame**

```r
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(num_in_group=seq_along(Species)) %>% 
  as.data.frame


    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species num_in_group
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa            1
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa            2
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa            3
..           ...         ...          ...         ...     ......           ..
48           4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa           48
49           5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa           49
50           5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa           50
51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor            1
52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor            2
53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor            3
..           ...         ...          ...         ...     ......           ..
98           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor           48
99           5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor           49
100          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor           50
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica            1
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica            2
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica            3
..           ...         ...          ...         ...     ......           ..
148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica           48
149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica           49
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica           50
```

Answer (score 1):

In `devel` version of `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(num = row_number(), .by = "cat")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another **base R solution** would be to `split` the data frame per `cat`, after that using `lapply`: add a column with number `1:nrow(x)`. The last step is to have your final data frame back with `do.call`, that is:

```
        df_split <- split(df, df$cat)
        df_lapply <- lapply(df_split, function(x) {
          x$num <- seq_len(nrow(x))
          return(x)
        })
        df <- do.call(rbind, df_lapply)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `collapse`/`data.table` solution which uses a grouped cumulative sum on a sequence of ones.

```r
library(data.table)
library(collapse)

set.seed(100) 
df <- data.table(cat = c(rep("aaa", 5), rep("bbb", 5), rep("ccc", 5)), 
                 val = runif(15))
setorder(df, cat, val)

df[, id := fcumsum(alloc(1L, .N), g = cat)][]
#>     cat        val id
#>  1: aaa 0.05638315  1
#>  2: aaa 0.25767250  2
#>  3: aaa 0.30776611  3
#>  4: aaa 0.46854928  4
#>  5: aaa 0.55232243  5
#>  6: bbb 0.17026205  1
#>  7: bbb 0.37032054  2
#>  8: bbb 0.48377074  3
#>  9: bbb 0.54655860  4
#> 10: bbb 0.81240262  5
#> 11: ccc 0.28035384  1
#> 12: ccc 0.39848790  2
#> 13: ccc 0.62499648  3
#> 14: ccc 0.76255108  4
#> 15: ccc 0.88216552  5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>