# How to assign a counter to a specific subset of a data.frame which is defined by a factor combination?

Tags: r, indexing, combinations, tapply

My question is: I have a data frame with some factor variables. I now want to assign a new vector to this data frame, which creates an index for each subset of those factor variables.

```
   data <-data.frame(fac1=factor(rep(1:2,5)), fac2=sample(letters[1:3],10,rep=T))
```

Gives me something like:

```
        fac1 fac2
     1     1    a
     2     2    c
     3     1    b
     4     2    a
     5     1    c
     6     2    b
     7     1    a
     8     2    a
     9     1    b
     10    2    c
```

And what I want is a combination counter which counts the occurrence of each factor combination. Like this

```
        fac1 fac2  counter
     1     1    a        1
     2     2    c        1
     3     1    b        1
     4     2    a        1
     5     1    c        1
     6     2    b        1
     7     1    a        2
     8     2    a        2
     9     1    b        2
     10    1    a        3
```

So far I thought about using tapply to get the counter over all factor-combinations, which works fine

```
counter <-tapply(data$fac1, list(data$fac1,data$fac2), function(x) 1:length(x))
```

But I do not know how I can assign the counter list (e.g. unlisted) to the combinations in the data-frame without using inefficient looping :)

Comment: Does it need to be in order or do you just want net counts? If you just want counts, table(paste(data$fac1,data$fac2,sep="-")) might help.

Comment: Hi! Within each fac1 x fac2 combination the order matters. (One can think of it as times a person "fac1" saw the letter "fac2")

Comment: You could use the same basic strategy, but switch from `tapply` to either `ddply` from **plyr**, or if your data is huge and performance is an issue, `data.table`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [numbering rows within groups in a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a job for the `ave()` function:

```
# Use set.seed for reproducible examples 
#   when random number generation is involved
set.seed(1) 
myDF <- data.frame(fac1 = factor(rep(1:2, 7)), 
                   fac2 = sample(letters[1:3], 14, replace = TRUE), 
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
myDF$counter <- ave(myDF$fac2, myDF$fac1, myDF$fac2, FUN = seq_along)
myDF
#    fac1 fac2 counter
# 1     1    a       1
# 2     2    b       1
# 3     1    b       1
# 4     2    c       1
# 5     1    a       2
# 6     2    c       2
# 7     1    c       1
# 8     2    b       2
# 9     1    b       2
# 10    2    a       1
# 11    1    a       3
# 12    2    a       2
# 13    1    c       2
# 14    2    b       3
```

Note the use of `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `data.frame()` step. If you didn't have that, you can still get the output with: `myDF$counter <- ave(as.character(myDF$fac2), myDF$fac1, myDF$fac2, FUN = seq_along)`.

Comment: Compared  mrdwab and my solution in terms of efficiency (could not get @mplourde to work) and the mrdwab is twice as fast. For 1000000 lines it is 1.693 vs. 3.382 sec

Answer (score 4):

A data.table solution

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(data)
DT[, counter := seq_len(.N), by = list(fac1, fac2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a base R way that avoids (explicit) looping.

```
data$counter <- with(data, {
    inter <- as.character(interaction(fac1, fac2))
    names(inter) <- seq_along(inter)
    inter.ordered <- inter[order(inter)]
    counter <- with(rle(inter.ordered), unlist(sapply(lengths, sequence)))
    counter[match(names(inter), names(inter.ordered))]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a variant with a little looping (I have renamed your variable to "x" since "data" is being used otherwise):

```
x <-data.frame(fac1=rep(1:2,5), fac2=sample(letters[1:3],10,rep=T))
x$fac3 <- paste( x$fac1, x$fac2, sep="" )
x$ctr <- 1
y <- table( x$fac3 )
for( i in 1 : length( rownames( y ) ) )
  x$ctr[x$fac3 == rownames(y)[i]] <- 1:length( x$ctr[x$fac3 == rownames(y)[i]] )
x <- x[-3]
```

No idea whether this is efficient over a large data.frame but it works!