# ID rows to columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns, rows

I suppose my problem should be pretty easy to solve.

So I got this df:

```
df1
ID STATUS.x STATUS.y
1  A        N
2  B        A
3  N        N
4  B        A
4  B        B
5  N        B
```

What I would like to generate is to combine the same ID's not in multiple rows but in multiple columns:

```
df2
ID STATUS.x STATUS.y STATUS.x1 STATUS.y1
1  A        N
2  B        A
3  N        N
4  B        A        B         B
5  N        B
```

Is thats possible?

Thanks a lot, Andrea

Comment: Can an ID only occur in the data set one to two times?  For example, there could never be three or more 4s?

Comment: Nope, we can have it multiple times unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `tidyverse`. `select(ID, ends_with("1"), ends_with("2"))` is optional. The purpose is just to order the columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  gather(STATUS, Value, -ID) %>%
  group_by(ID, STATUS) %>%
  mutate(Row = row_number()) %>%
  unite("STATUS_new", STATUS, Row, sep = ".") %>%
  spread(STATUS_new, Value) %>%
  select(ID, ends_with("1"), ends_with("2")) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#      ID STATUS.x.1 STATUS.y.1 STATUS.x.2 STATUS.y.2
#   <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
# 1     1 A          N          NA         NA        
# 2     2 B          A          NA         NA        
# 3     3 N          N          NA         NA        
# 4     4 B          A          B          B         
# 5     5 N          B          NA         NA
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID STATUS.x STATUS.y
1  A        N
                  2  B        A
                  3  N        N
                  4  B        A
                  4  B        B
                  5  N        B",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: i got this error actually: Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: You got it in the example data frame or your real-world data?

Comment: In the real one, that is actually pretty much the same... which one could be the problem? there are just 2 more useless columns

Comment: I don't have this error so I don't know. Google leads me to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593791/dplyr-row-number-error-in-rank, which could be useful.

Comment: Ok now it works fine but just for 1 time and not for multiple time; i.e. if there are 4 times the same ID it just works for the first couple and delete the other cases

Comment: If you have more than two cases, you will need to modify `select(ID, ends_with("1"), ends_with("2"))`. That line only assumes that there are two multiple records.

Comment: Works perfectly ^^