# Increment by one to each duplicate value

Tags: r, duplicates, sequence

I am trying to find a proper way, in R, to find duplicated values, and add the value 1 to each subsequent duplicated value grouped by id. For example:

```
data = data.table(id = c('1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2'),
                  value = c(95,100,101,101,101,20,35,38))

data$new_value <- ifelse(data[ , data$value] == lag(data$value,1),
                         lag(data$value, 1) + 1 ,data$value)
data$desired_value <- c(95,100,101,102,103,20,35,38)
```

Produces:

```
   id value new_value desired_value
1:  1    95        NA            95
2:  1   100       100           100
3:  1   101       101           101 # first 101 in id 1: add 0
4:  1   101       102           102 # second 101 in id 1: add 1
5:  1   101       102           103 # third 101 in id 1: add 2
6:  2    20        20            20
7:  2    35        35            35
8:  2    38        38            38
```

I tried doing this with `ifelse`, but it doesn't work recursively so it only applies to the following row, and not any subsequent rows. Also the `lag` function results in me losing the first value in `value`.

I've seen examples with character variables with `make.names` or `make.unique`, but haven't been able to find a solution for a duplicated numeric value.

Background: I am doing a survival analysis and I am finding that with my data there are stop times that are the same, so I need to make it unique by adding a 1 (stop times are in seconds).

Comment: Related: [Numbering rows within groups in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an attempt. You're essentially grouping by `id` and `value` and adding `0:(length(value)-1)`. So:

```
data[, onemore := value + (0:(.N-1)), by=.(id, value)]

#   id value new_value desired_value onemore
#1:  1    95        96            95      95
#2:  1   100       101           100     100
#3:  1   101       102           101     101
#4:  1   101       102           102     102
#5:  1   101       102           103     103
#6:  2    20        21            20      20
#7:  2    35        36            35      35
#8:  2    38        39            38      38
```

Comment: @akrun and @thelatemail I see. So here we use the "by" to group, which .N handles and becomes the total number of observations in that group. With `101` appearing 3 times within id `1`, .N = 3, or `(0:(3-1))`. That results in `value + (0:2)`, or simply `value + 0, value +1, value +2`. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

With base R we can use `ave` where we take the first value of each group and basically add the row number of that row in that group.

```
data$value1 <- ave(data$value, data$id, data$value, FUN = function(x)
                                                      x[1] + seq_along(x) - 1)

#   id value new_value desired_value value1
#1:  1    95        96            95     95
#2:  1   100       101           100    100
#3:  1   101       102           101    101
#4:  1   101       102           102    102
#5:  1   101       102           103    103
#6:  2    20        21            20     20
#7:  2    35        36            35     35
#8:  2    38        39            38     38
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(id, value) %>%
    mutate(onemore = value + row_number()-1)
#     id value onemore
#  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1    95      95
#2     1   100     100
#3     1   101     101
#4     1   101     102
#5     1   101     103
#6     2    20      20
#7     2    35      35
#8     2    38      38
```

---

Or we can use `base R` without anonymous function call

```
data$onemore <- with(data, value + ave(value, id, value, FUN =seq_along)-1)
data$onemore
#[1]  95 100 101 102 103  20  35  38
```

Comment: What is the problem with the solution?  Why downvoting a legitimate solution?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid (a potentially costly) `by`, you may use `rowid`:

```
data[, res := value + rowid(id, value) - 1]
# data
#    id value new_value desired_value res
# 1:  1    95        96            95  95
# 2:  1   100       101           100 100
# 3:  1   101       102           101 101
# 4:  1   101       102           102 102
# 5:  1   101       102           103 103
# 6:  2    20        21            20  20
# 7:  2    35        36            35  35
# 8:  2    38        39            38  38
```