# If 2 columns of data have the same values in the row above it, then add 0.00001 to it

Tags: r, loops, decimal

I have a data frame that contains a column for Latitude and a column for Longitude that looks like this

```
test <- data.frame("Latitude" = c(45.14565, 45.14565, 45.14565, 45.14565, 33.2222, 
31.22122, 31.22122), "Longitude" = c(-105.6666, -105.6666, -105.6666, -104.3333, 
-104.3333, -105.77777, -105.77777))
```

I would like to make every value go out to 5 decimal places and also check to see that if a latitude and longitude pair are the same as the pair above it, to add 0.00001 to both the latitude and the longitude value. So my data would change to this:

```
test_updated <- data.frame("Latitude" = c(45.14565, 45.14566, 45.14567, 45.14565, 
33.22220, 31.22122, 31.22123), "Longitude" = c(-105.66660, -105.66661, -105.66662, 
-104.33330, -104.33330, -105.77777, -105.77778))
```

Comment: Related: [Increment by one to each duplicate value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196718/increment-by-one-to-each-duplicate-value-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which updates the `Latitude` column in `test` to reproduce OP's expected result:

```
options(digits = 8) # required to print all significant digits of Longitude
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, `:=`(Latitude  = Latitude  + (seq(.N) - 1) * 0.00001,
                   Longitude = Longitude + (seq(.N) - 1) * 0.00001), 
            by = .(Latitude, Longitude)]
test
```

> ```
>    Latitude  Longitude
> 1: 45.14565 -105.66660
> 2: 45.14566 -105.66659
> 3: 45.14567 -105.66658
> 4: 45.14565 -104.33330
> 5: 33.22220 -104.33330
> 6: 31.22122 -105.77777
> 7: 31.22123 -105.77776
> ```

For comparison

```
test_updated
```

> ```
>   Latitude  Longitude
> 1 45.14565 -105.66660
> 2 45.14566 -105.66661
> 3 45.14567 -105.66662
> 4 45.14565 -104.33330
> 5 33.22220 -104.33330
> 6 31.22122 -105.77777
> 7 31.22123 -105.77778
> ```

The discrepancy is caused by OP's requirement *to add 0.00001 to both the latitude and the longitude value* and OP's expected result where
0.00001 have been *subtracted* from the *negative* longitude values.

#### Edit

In order to reproduce the expected result, the sign of the value has to be considered. Unfortunately the base R `sign()` function returns zero for `sign(0)`. So, we use `fifelse(x < 0, -1, 1)` instead.

In addition, we can pick up [Henrik's splendid idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68637644/if-2-columns-of-data-have-the-same-values-in-the-row-above-it-then-add-0-00001/68639071?noredirect=1#comment121304639_68639071) to use the `rowid()` function to avoid grouping.

```
options(digits = 8) # required to print all significant digits of Longitude
library(data.table)
cols <- c("Latitude", "Longitude")
setDT(test)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) x + fifelse(x < 0, -1, 1) * 
                                 (rowidv(.SD, cols) - 1) * 0.00001), .SDcols = cols]
test
```

> ```
>    Latitude  Longitude
> 1: 45.14565 -105.66660
> 2: 45.14566 -105.66661
> 3: 45.14567 -105.66662
> 4: 45.14565 -104.33330
> 5: 33.22220 -104.33330
> 6: 31.22122 -105.77777
> 7: 31.22123 -105.77778
> ```

Comment: Or `test[, Latitude := Latitude + (rowid(Latitude, Longitude) - 1) * 0.00001]`, to avoid `by`.

Comment: @Henrik, Splendid idea!

Answer (score 0):

As usual there is no need to use a loop:

```
library(dplyr)
test_updated = test %>% 
    mutate(
        across(c(Latitude, Longitutde), 
            function(x) if_else(x == lag(x), x+0.00001, x)
            )
        )

format(round(test_updated, 5), nsmall = 5)
```

```
  Latitude Longitutde
1 45.14566 -105.66659
2 45.14566 -105.66659
3 45.14566 -105.66659
4 45.14566 -104.33329
5 33.22221 -104.33329
6 31.22123 -105.77776
7 31.22123 -105.77776
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but maybe something like this?

```
rm(list=ls())

n <- nrow(test)
test_updated <- data.frame(Latitude = double(n),
                       Longitude = double(n))

add <- 0.00001
test_updated[1,] <- test[1,]
for (i in 2:nrow(test)){
  if(test$Latitude[i-1] == test$Latitude[i] & test$Longitutde[i-1] == test$Longitutde[i]){
    test_updated$Latitude[i] <- test$Latitude[i] + add
    test_updated$Longitude[i] <- test$Longitutde[i] + add
   } else{
     test_updated[i,] <- test[i,]
  }
}
```