# How to break ties in a ranking with gaps in ranking

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Say that I have these data:

```
data <- data.frame(orig=c(1,5,5,5,14,18,18,25))

  orig
1    1
2    5
3    5
4    5
5   14
6   18
7   18
8   25
```

I would like to create the `want` column:

```
  orig want
1    1    1
2    5    5
3    5    6
4    5    7
5   14   14
6   18   18
7   18   19
8   25   25
```

This column takes `orig` and copies its value, but breaks ties if they exist. What I am trying to do is to re-create the rankings so that there are no ties and the ties are broken based on the order of the rows in the dataset. If not for the spaces in the rankings (jump from 1 to 5, etc.), I could use

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% mutate(test = rank(orig, ties.method="min"))
```

But this of course doesn't get me what I want:

```
  orig test
1    1    1
2    5    2
3    5    2
4    5    2
5   14    5
6   18    6
7   18    6
8   25    8
```

What can I do?

Comment: Related: [Increment by one to each duplicate value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196718/increment-by-one-to-each-duplicate-value). Can you have something like `c(1, 1, 1, 2)`? If not, you find the answers in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may add `row_number()` after grouping

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(orig) %>% 
     mutate(want = orig + row_number() - 1) %>%
     ungroup
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
   orig  want
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     5     5
3     5     6
4     5     7
5    14    14
6    18    18
7    18    19
8    25    25
```

---

Or may simplify with `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data %>% 
     mutate(want = orig + rowid(orig)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `ave` + `seq_along`

```
transform(
  data,
  want = orig + ave(orig, orig, FUN = seq_along) - 1
)
```

gives

```
  orig want
1    1    1
2    5    5
3    5    6
4    5    7
5   14   14
6   18   18
7   18   19
8   25   25
```