# Sort and number rows by fields

Tags: r

I have my data.frame:

```
name  session_start
Mike  100
Mike  50
York  300
Mike  200
York  100
```

I need to number rows by name and ascending `session_start` column, like this:

```
name  session_start  number
Mike    50            1
Mike    100           2
Mike    200           3
York    100           1
York    300           2
```

P.S sorry for  my english

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame . You basically just need to order first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummy solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
# Example data
d <- data.table(name = c("Mike", "Mike", "York", "Mike", "York"),
                session_start = c(100, 50, 300, 200, 100))
# Solution
d[, number := order(session_start), name]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can sort `df` with `order` first and then create new column with `ave`:

```
df <- df[order(df$name, df$session_start), ]

df$number <- ave(df$session_start, df$name, FUN = rank)

# > df
#   name session_start number
# 2 Mike            50      1
# 1 Mike           100      2
# 4 Mike           200      3
# 5 York           100      1
# 3 York           300      2
```