# Selecting top N rows for each group based on value in column

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr, top-n

I have dataframe like below :-

```
x<-c(3,2,1,8,7,11,10,9,7,5,4)
y<-c("a","a","a", "b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c")
z<-c(2,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3)
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)

df
    x y z
1   3 a 2
2   2 a 2
3   1 a 2
4   8 b 1
5   7 b 1
6  11 c 3
7  10 c 3
8   9 c 3
9   7 c 3
10  5 c 3
11  4 c 3
```

I want to select top n row for each group by column y where n is provided in column z. 
So the output should be like :

```
output:
       x   y  z
     1 3   a  2
     2 2   a  2
     3 8   b  1
     4 11  c  3
     5 10  c  3
     6 9   c  3
```

Comment: Would `z` values be always same for a group? What if they are different? How to select `n`?

Comment: z values are always same for a group.So n value for group "a" is 2 ,for "b" is 1 and for "c" is 3.

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(y) %>% slice(1:z[1])` should work.

Comment: @HNSKD your code works.. but in case two values in column x is similar  for a group then  ?

Comment: in that case you can add `unique()` before `slice()`

Comment: thanks @Prem and@HNSKD df %>% group_by(y) %>% unique()%>% slice(1:z[1]) is what i was looking for.

Comment: @vsb You've received a few good answers below. If one of them worked for you, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer. This lets the community know the answer solved your issue and that the issue should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with base R:

```
# df is split according to y, then we keep only the top "z" value (after ordering x) 
# and rbind everything back together:
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(df, df$y), 
               function(df1) df1[order(df1$x, decreasing=TRUE), ][1:unique(df1$z), ]))
#     x y z
#a.1  3 a 2
#a.2  2 a 2
#b    8 b 1
#c.6 11 c 3
#c.7 10 c 3
#c.8  9 c 3
```

**EDIT:**
A much more direct way (still in base `R`) provided in comment by @mt1022:

```
df[ave(1:nrow(df), df$y, FUN = seq_along) <= df$z, ]
#   x y z
#1  3 a 2
#2  2 a 2
#4  8 b 1
#6 11 c 3
#7 10 c 3
#8  9 c 3
```

Comment: Another base R solution: `df[ave(1:nrow(df), df$y, FUN = seq_along) <= as.numeric(df$z), ]`

Comment: @mt1022 I should get more familiar with `ave` ;-), this is much better base R solution, you should post that

Comment: It is adapted from this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame. I just add a filter step. Maybe you can add it to your answer as an alternative way.

Comment: @mt1022 thanks, I'll add it but feel free to change your mind and post and I'll delete the edit ;-)

Comment: @mt1022 but this is assuming the data is _descendingly_ sorted.

Comment: @RonakShah, sure. If the data are not already in right order, an additional `order(-as.numeric(df$x))` is required.

Answer (score 1):

One approach with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,.(inc=seq_len(.N)<=z,x,z),by=.(y)][inc==T ,-2]
#   y  x z
#1: a  3 2
#2: a  2 2
#3: b  8 1
#4: c 11 3
#5: c 10 3
#6: c  9 3
```

Comment: Or just `df[, .SD[seq_len(.N) <= z], by = y]`

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `dplyr` that uses `do`:

```
df %>%
   group_by(y) %>%
   do(head(.,as.numeric(unique(.$z))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the solution I was looking for using dplyr. It is based on @HNSKD:

```
library(dplyr)
x<-c(3,2,1,8,7,11,10,9,7,5,4)
y<-c("a","a","a", "b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c")
z<-c(2,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3)

df<-data.frame(x,y,z)

df %>% group_by(y) %>% slice(1:2)
```

Which returns the first two elements for each `y`:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   y [3]
      x y         z
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
1     3 a         2
2     2 a         2
3     8 b         1
4     7 b         1
5    11 c         3
6    10 c         3
```