# Indexing based on consecutive field values

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I have a `data.table` in R tracking the movement of items within a system. I'd like to group these data based on two fields, `ID` and `Location`.

```
library(data.table)
example <- data.table(ID = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 6),
                      Location = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,1,3))
example
#     ID Location
#  1:  A        1
#  2:  A        2
#  3:  A        3
#  4:  A        1
#  5:  A        2
#  6:  A        1
#  7:  B        2
#  8:  B        2
#  9:  B        2
# 10:  B        3
# 11:  B        3
# 12:  B        1
# 13:  C        2
# 14:  C        3
# 15:  C        3
# 16:  C        3
# 17:  C        1
# 18:  C        3
```

What I would like to have as an output is a new column with a number that increments each time the location changes, regardless of what the new location is (i.e. if that location exists elsewhere in the history). Rather the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12925063/698590), which increments only within the group.

```
expected_output <- data.table(ID = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 6),
                     Location = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,1,3),
                     Group = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,4))
expected_output
#     ID Location Group
#  1:  A        1     1
#  2:  A        2     2
#  3:  A        3     3
#  4:  A        1     4
#  5:  A        2     5
#  6:  A        1     6
#  7:  B        2     1
#  8:  B        2     1
#  9:  B        2     1
# 10:  B        3     2
# 11:  B        3     2
# 12:  B        1     3
# 13:  C        2     1
# 14:  C        3     2
# 15:  C        3     2
# 16:  C        3     2
# 17:  C        1     3
# 18:  C        3     4
```

I've tried a few different combinations of `by` arguments with little luck so far. The closest I seem to be able to get is something with `diff` which partially correctly shows when the change occurs, but increments internally.

```
output <- example
output[, Group := 1:.N, by = paste0(ID, Location, diff(Location))]
output
#     ID Location Group
#  1:  A        1     1 
#  2:  A        2     1 # not incrementing/new group
#  3:  A        3     1 # not incrementing/new group
#  4:  A        1     2
#  5:  A        2     1
#  6:  A        1     3
#  7:  B        2     1
#  8:  B        2     2 # incrementing when shouldn't
#  9:  B        2     1 
# 10:  B        3     1 
# 11:  B        3     1
# 12:  B        1     1
# 13:  C        2     1
# 14:  C        3     1
# 15:  C        3     2
# 16:  C        3     1
# 17:  C        1     1
# 18:  C        3     1
```

At this point, I'm pretty lost, though I'm sure the solution is staring me in the face.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by `ID` and then take the `rleid` of `Location` column:

```
example[, Group := rleid(Location), ID]
example
#    ID Location Group
# 1:  A        1     1
# 2:  A        2     2
# 3:  A        3     3
# 4:  A        1     4
# 5:  A        2     5
# 6:  A        1     6
# 7:  B        2     1
# 8:  B        2     1
# 9:  B        2     1
#10:  B        3     2
#11:  B        3     2
#12:  B        1     3
#13:  C        2     1
#14:  C        3     2
#15:  C        3     2
#16:  C        3     2
#17:  C        1     3
#18:  C        3     4

all.equal(example, expected_output)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, thank you! I had no knowledge of `rleid` previously. Will accept as soon as SO allows me to.