# Counting the number of occurrences of a value in R

Tags: r, vector

If I have a vector of numbers in R.

```
numbers <- c(1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4,4,4,4, 1)
```

I want to return a vector that provides the number of times that value has occurred cumulatively along the vector. I.e.

```
results <- c(1,2, 1,2,3, 1,2, 1,2,3,4, 3)
```

Comment: [Numbering rows within groups in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame).

Comment: As posted in the link to henrik's comment, `data.table::rowid(numbers)` also returns the desired result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `ave` and apply the `seq_along` by grouping with the 'numbers' `vector`

```
ave(numbers, numbers, FUN = seq_along)
#[1] 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 3 4 3
```