# create a vector with values that have a tally of the different values in another vector

Tags: r, vector, counter

Say that I have the following vector:

```
dat <- c(1,0,-1,1,0,-1,1,0,1)
```

I want a vector that counts the occurences of 1, 0 an -1 in dat but as an ongoing tally. The solution would look like so:

```
tally <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
```

So essentially my new vector has an ongoing tally of 1, 0 and -1 from dat. I am looking for a way to do this calculation in R so I can use it on a much larger set.

Comment: This isn't well defined. Are the values in `dat` always to be taken in chunks of three? How do you know which values in `tally` are counting which values? Or do you mean that `tally` should be read positionally?

Comment: The very first answer here works fine with vectors: [Numbering rows within groups in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: @joran Apologies, the only possible values in dat will be in {1, 0 ,-1} but they will not be bunched in threes (i.e the distribution of the {1, 0, -1} in dat is random). And yes, I mean that tally should be read positionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple approach:

```
> dat <- c(1,0,-1,1,0,-1,1,0,1)
> tally <- ave(dat, factor(dat), FUN=seq_along)
> tally
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

The `ave` function splits the `dat` vector apart by the unique values in `dat` (-1, 0, and 1 in this case), then `seq_along` is a quick and dirty way to get the running tally for each unique value, then `ave` puts the separate cumulative counts back together in the order to match the original data.

Comment: Thank you, this is the type of answer I was looking for. EDIT: ran it on a very big vector and it had excellent run time!

Comment: I have quick follow up, would you know how to calculate the consecutive run length of each value? i.e for `dat <- c(1,1,1,0,-1, -1)` we would have `run <- c(3,3,3,1,2,2)` because there are three 1s in a row, one 0 in a row and two -1s in a row. So basically just having a running tally of the consecutive run length,

Comment: @Chris95, `tmp <- rle(dat); rep(tmp$lengths, each=tmp$lengths)`

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- c(1,0,-1,1,0,-1,1,0,1)

new_vec <- NULL
count_this <- function(vec) {
    for(i in 1:length(vec)) {
    this_elem = vec[i]
    before_vec <- vec[1:i]
    contains_vec <- before_vec[before_vec == this_elem]
    new_vec[i] <- length(contains_vec)
    }
    return(new_vec)
}
```

Use like this:

```
count_this(dat)

1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

But definitely use Greg's much more efficient approach:

```
dat_long <- round(rnorm(10000), 0)

start.time <- Sys.time()
res_a <- count_this(dat_long)
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
p_1 <- as.vector(time.taken)

start.time <- Sys.time()
res_b <- ave(dat_long, factor(dat_long), FUN=seq_along)
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
p_2 <- as.vector(time.taken)

final <- data.frame(For_Loop = p_1, Vectorized = p_2)
mp <- barplot(as.matrix(final), col='steelblue', beside=T, main='Runtimes for Tally Algoritm')
```

[image]