# How to add a new time sequence to data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame of unknown length with recordings of SkinTemp for different people (id). I would like to create a vector with time stamps (1/32s) for each id. I don't know how long each recording is.

```
df<-data.frame(
               SkinTemp=rnorm(65,37,0.5),
               id=rep(1:10,c(5,4,10,6,7,8,9,8,4,4)))
```

**edit:**

I have worked out how to do it using rle by adapting this answer [Numbering rows within groups in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame)

```
df$Time <- sequence(rle(as.character(df$id))$lengths)/32
```

edit 2:

I have realised this does not work exactly as it starts from 1/32 instead of 0. The dplyr answer using (row_number -1)/32 works better.

Comment: `df$Time <- df$Time/32`. Or you can set when creating the data frame: `Time=seq(65)/32`

Comment: I've cleaned the question up. I would like to make the time sequence for each id but I don't know how long each one is.

Comment: What information do you have about the times then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the time stamp is 1/32, 2/32, 3/32...n/32, where `n` is the number of rows *per id*.

So using `dplyr` to group by id should work:

EDIT: now uses `(row_number() - 1)` to start from 0.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(SkinTemp = rnorm(65, 37, 0.5),
                  id = rep(1:10, c(5, 4, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 4, 4)))

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(ts = (row_number() - 1) / 32) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 65 x 3
   SkinTemp    id     ts
      <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
 1     36.7     1 0     
 2     36.9     1 0.0312
 3     37.8     1 0.0625
 4     37.0     1 0.0938
 5     37.1     1 0.125 
 6     37.9     2 0     
 7     37.2     2 0.0312
 8     36.4     2 0.0625
 9     36.7     2 0.0938
10     36.8     3 0    # ... with 55 more rows
```

Comment: Love it, thank you very much! I knew there was a nice dplyr version out there!

Comment: Oh, I've just realised it starts at 1/32 not 0...

Comment: So I guess `(row_number - 1) / 32` works.