# Get last row that matches conditions in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have data that looks like this:

```
d <- data.table(SEQ = c(1, 1, 2, 2,
                        1, 2, 2, 3,
                        1, 1, 2, 3,
                        3, 4, 5, 5),
                TYPE = c("A", "A", "B", "B",
                         "C", "C", "C", "C",
                         "D", "D", "D", "D",
                         "D", "D", "D", "D"), 
                CLASS = c(1.1, 2.1, 3.3, 4.5,
                          1.3, 2.4, 3.4, 4.6,
                          1.4, 2.5, 3.6, 4.0,
                          1.4, 2.7, 3.2, 4.5))
```

That looks like this:

[image: data]

I want to filter this down into a new table, call it `b`.
The logic for filtering would be for each `unique(TYPE)` only keep the last row for each `unique(SEQ)`. I know I can get this done with some `for` loops but I would like to avoid that.

The expected output for the sample data would be:

[image: expected output]

If anyone has any suggestions of efficient ways to filter, I am all ears. Thanks!

Comment: `unique(d, by=c("SEQ", "TYPE"), fromLast=TRUE)` should work... seeing if I can find a dupe...

Comment: Check this answer, if you need some ordering https://stackoverflow.com/a/50906379/5795592

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to *group by* using both groups, and then use `.N` to select the last line within each subset of data, ie `.SD` :

```
R> d[, .SD[.N], by=.(SEQ,TYPE)]
    SEQ TYPE CLASS
 1:   1    A   2.1
 2:   2    B   4.5
 3:   1    C   1.3
 4:   2    C   3.4
 5:   3    C   4.6
 6:   1    D   2.5
 7:   2    D   3.6
 8:   3    D   1.4
 9:   4    D   2.7
10:   5    D   4.5
R>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(TYPE, SSEQ) %>% filter(row_number() == max(row_number()))
#     SEQ TYPE  CLASS
# 1     1 A       2.1
# 2     2 B       4.5
# 3     1 C       1.3
# 4     2 C       3.4
# 5     3 C       4.6
# 6     1 D       2.5
# 7     2 D       3.6
# 8     3 D       1.4
# 9     4 D       2.7
#10     5 D       4.5
```

Comment: You need two groups, look at his reference output.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. Editing now. Thanks.

Comment: You could also try mentioning the package you are using

Comment: Absolutely, I apologize for its omission.