# merging two dataframes based on one column without duplicating rows and preserving more data

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

My goal is to merge two large dataframes based on column `genus`, but with the special condition of not duplicating rows (not solved in first try); and also preserving more information from both dataframes (not solved in  second try), please see desired output:

```
chromdata <- read.table(text="
 genus sp
1      Acosta       Acosta_1
2    Aguilera     Aguilera_1
3      Acosta       Acosta_2
4    Aguilera     Aguilera_2
5       other              1   # EDIT: new rows    
6       other              2",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

treedata <- read.table(text="
 genus sp
1      Acosta       Acosta_3
2    Aguilera     Aguilera_3
3      Acosta       Acosta_4
4    Aguilera     Aguilera_4
5       other              3",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#First try
merge(chromdata,treedata, by="genus", all=F)

#Second try
chromdata$sp2<-treedata$sp[match(chromdata$genus, treedata$genus)]
chromdata
     genus         sp        sp2
1   Acosta   Acosta_1   Acosta_3
2 Aguilera Aguilera_1 Aguilera_3
3   Acosta   Acosta_2   Acosta_3 #Acosta_4 missing
4 Aguilera Aguilera_2 Aguilera_3 # Aguilera_4 missing
5    other          1          3
6    other          2          3
```

Desired Output:

```
     genus         sp        sp2
1   Acosta   Acosta_1   Acosta_3
2 Aguilera Aguilera_1 Aguilera_3
3   Acosta   Acosta_2   Acosta_4
4 Aguilera Aguilera_2 Aguilera_4
5    other          1          3 # EDIT: new rows
6    other          2          3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add another column to merge on:

```
library(data.table)
merge(
  transform(chromdata, r = rowid(genus)), 
  transform(treedata, r = rowid(genus)), 
  by=c("r", "genus")
)

  r    genus       sp.x       sp.y
1 1   Acosta   Acosta_1   Acosta_3
2 1 Aguilera Aguilera_1 Aguilera_3
3 2   Acosta   Acosta_2   Acosta_4
4 2 Aguilera Aguilera_2 Aguilera_4
```

You could also get rowid like `ave(genus, genus, FUN = seq_along)` or [many other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12925063/) if you don't want to load data.table.

Comment: I found a case in which the answer does not work, see edit.

Comment: solved adding  , all.x=T) in your function; library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(genus) %>% fill(sp.y)

Answer (score 0):

I want to elaborate more on the data.table approach.

First of all, you could read your data then directly transform it to a data.table object:

```
library(data.table)

chromdata <- as.data.table(read.table(text="
 genus sp
                        1      Acosta       Acosta_1
                        2    Aguilera     Aguilera_1
                        3      Acosta       Acosta_2
                        4    Aguilera     Aguilera_2",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

treedata <- as.data.table(read.table(text="
                       genus sp
                       1      Acosta       Acosta_3
                       2    Aguilera     Aguilera_3
                       3      Acosta       Acosta_4
                       4    Aguilera     Aguilera_4",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

After that, you need an extra column for the merge operation required to achieve your desired output :

```
chromdata[, N := seq_len(.N), genus]
treedata[, N := seq_len(.N), genus]
```

These lines gives you the row ids within groups.

Lastly, with the help of data.table package, we can merge these two tables on common columns:

```
chromdata[treedata, on = c("genus", "N")]
```

The final output :

```
      genus         sp N       i.sp
1:   Acosta   Acosta_1 1   Acosta_3
2: Aguilera Aguilera_1 1 Aguilera_3
3:   Acosta   Acosta_2 2   Acosta_4
4: Aguilera Aguilera_2 2 Aguilera_4
```

Comment: this is similar to the rowidv function.

Comment: @Ferroao I know, as I said I wanted to elaborate more on data.table perspective

Comment: rowidv is also data.table