# Creating a list based on nth appearance of variable. Thank you

Tags: r

I want to be able to see how many times a value has already been listed in the dataset. Thank you!!

`test = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "c")`
I want to be able to return `new_variable = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1)` based on the information above

Comment: Is test a vector or a dataframe?

Comment: I'm guessing I'll have to sort and then create a for loop? or a sequence function?

Comment: test is a vector

Comment: Essentially you are doing this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame - where the variable and the group are the same - `as.numeric(ave(test,test,FUN=seq_along))` as a base example or you could use one of the countless other methods using your favourite out of packages like `dplyr` or `data.table`

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)


test = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "c")

resulting_vector <- test %>% as_tibble() %>%
    group_by(value) %>%
    mutate(total = row_number()) %>%
    pull(total)

resulting_vector
```