# How to fix 'Error: matrix/data.frame criterion should be logical.'

Tags: r, dataframe, countif

I can't find the

> Error: matrix/data.frame criterion should be logical.

in my code.

```
#count prod_no downward
consoContact2$Count <- as.numeric("")
for (xNo in 1:nrow(consoContact2)){
  consoContact2$Count[xNo] <- count_if(consoContact2[xNo,1],consoContact2[1:xNo,1])
}
```

**Data sample:**

```
    Prod_No         Order_No    Reff_ID                       Count
1   03MB1902-118    920522XXXX  03MB1902-118'A**0920522XXXX NA
2   03MB1902-118    33333XXXX   03MB1902-118'C**033333XXXX  NA
3   07MB1902-105    922977XXXX  07MB1902-105'A**0922977XXXX NA
4   07MB1902-105    32231XXXX   07MB1902-105'C**032231XXXX  NA
5   07MB1902-105    32268XXXX   07MB1902-105'C**032268XXXX  NA
```

**These must be the output:**

```
    Prod_No         Order_No    Reff_ID                       Count
1   03MB1902-118    920522XXXX  03MB1902-118'A**0920522XXXX 1
2   03MB1902-118    33333XXXX   03MB1902-118'C**033333XXXX  2
3   07MB1902-105    922977XXXX  07MB1902-105'A**0922977XXXX 1
4   07MB1902-105    32231XXXX   07MB1902-105'C**032231XXXX  2
5   07MB1902-105    32268XXXX   07MB1902-105'C**032268XXXX  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is simpler solved using the several solutions, some of which are stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame). As such this is a duplicate question. However, these do not use the `data.table` package, as such i'll provide an example here using this package. For more information check their [wiki page here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki). Additionally it seems the very last column of your data is logical, which should be changed to numeric

```
library(data.table)
#Change from data.frame to data.table
setDT(data_sample)
#set count to be numeric
data_sample[, Count := as.integer(Count)]
#Change count to be the format needed.
data_sample[, Count := seq(1,.N), by = Prod_No]
```

Comment: Hi Oliver,

Thank you for immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

This minor change should help you get the required output

```
consoContact2$Count <- as.numeric("")
for (xNo in 1:nrow(consoContact2)){
  consoContact2$Count[xNo] <- length(which(consoContact2$Prod_No[1:xNo] == consoContact2[xNo,1]))
}
```

Hope that helps.