# Is there an R function to redefine a variable so I can use the spread function?

Tags: r, reshape, spread

I'm new with R and I have the following problem. Maybe it's a really easy question, but I don't know the terms to search for an answer.

My problem: 
I have several persons, each person is assigned a studynumber (SN). And each SN has one or more tests being performed, the test can have multiple results. 
My data is long at the moment, but I need it to be wide (one row for each SN).

For example: 
What I have:

```
  SN testnumbers result
1  1        1234      6
2  1        1234      9
3  2        4567      6
4  3        5678      9
5  3        8790      9
```

What I want:

```
  SN test1result1 test1result2 test2result1
1  1            6            6           NA
2  2            6           NA           NA
3  3            9           NA            9
```

So I need to renumber the testnumbers into test 1 etc for each SN, in order to use the spread function, I think. But I don't know how.

I did manage to renumber testnumber into a list of 1 till the last unique testnumber, but still the wide dataframe looks awful.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, group by `SN`, then make a column of row numbers along each group? Several answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12925063/5325862

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It already helps a lot!