# How to create a repeating index based on a group, not within a group

Tags: r

I have an index with the following numbers (5, 10, 15, 17) This index is generated from a large csv file and corresponds to the order of these phrases from that file. Eventually id like to map these phrases back with the new columns my loop generates.

Each index is associated with a phrase. My code separates the phrase and creates columns based on words in the phrase. I need to create another column in my data frame with the index number that corresponds to each phrase.

```
For example: 
    column 1          column 2            index
    phrase A            book                5
    phrase A            tree                5
    phrase B            tree                10
```

How would I achieve this result within my loop and make sure the index is changing with every new input in column 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numbering rows within groups in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: `index = c(5, 10, 15, 17)`, `names(index) = c("phrase A", "phrase B", "phrase C", "phrase D")`. `your_data$index = index[your_data$column_1]`.

Comment: I think this is not a dupe of Numbering within groups - OP wants the *same* index value for each group.

Comment: @Gregor, Did you try it? Did it not work? Multiply by 5 ?

Comment: @Reeza the OP wants the numbers to correspond to column 1, not column 2. I think they just want a join to a table describing how phrases map to indexes? (since they specify that they need specific indexes not just any numbering)

Comment: Are the equal phrases consecutive?

Comment: Yeah, @Gregor, you're correct, I'm wrong! Thanks :)

Comment: So another added later to this is that the phrases can repeat and you can be extracting different things from it in column b. I just need to create a column that changes index each time a new phrase is run in the loop. The index and phrases are sequential

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
index_by <- function(DF, group, index_list = NULL){
  f <- ave(as.character(DF[[group]]), DF[[group]], FUN = function(x) rnorm(1))
  i <- as.integer(factor(f, levels = unique(f)))
  if(is.null(index_list)) i else index_list[i]
}

df1$index <- index_by(df1, "column1")
df1$index2 <- index_by(df1, "column1", c(5, 10, 15, 17))

df1
#    column1 index index2
#1  phrase 1     1      5
#2  phrase 1     1      5
#3  phrase 1     1      5
#4  phrase 1     1      5
#5  phrase 2     2     10
#6  phrase 2     2     10
#7  phrase 3     3     15
#8  phrase 3     3     15
#9  phrase 3     3     15
#10 phrase 4     4     17
```

**Data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- data.frame(column1 = paste("phrase", rep(1:4, sample(4))))
```

Comment: They are not going by increments of 5, the index is a list of completely random numbers based on the phrases

Comment: Then why does it matter if it's 5 or not?

Comment: @aa710 Then the same method would do it, just remove the multiply.

Comment: the index is generated based on where these phrases are in a large csv, eventually i need to map it back to that file so the index for each individual phrase matters here

Comment: Then you need to explain your base case better, I feel this answers the question you asked, but the question you asked is not the problem you actually want to solve.

Comment: This seems to work, but how would I modify this code to correspond to my index list? which would be in the same order the phrases appear? Instead of 1,2,3,4

Comment: @aa710 I have changed the function to have another argument, `index_list`. The function now defaults to consecutive numbers, pass the index list and it will use it instead. The example calls the function in both ways.

Comment: @aa710 the initial comment from Gregor answered this then, did you try his solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_indices()` within tidyverse. Here's an example that groups the `mpg` data set by the manufacturer.

```
library(tidyverse)

mpgGroupNbr <- mpg %>%
  arrange(manufacturer) %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
  mutate(groupNbr = group_indices()*5)

#check coding - max/min should be the same if coded correctly
mpgGroupNbr %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  summarize(max = max(groupNbr), min = min(groupNbr))
```

Results:

```
   manufacturer   max   min
    <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
 1 audi             5     5
 2 chevrolet       10    10
 3 dodge           15    15
 4 ford            20    20
 5 honda           25    25
 6 hyundai         30    30
 7 jeep            35    35
 8 land rover      40    40
 9 lincoln         45    45
10 mercury         50    50
11 nissan          55    55
12 pontiac         60    60
13 subaru          65    65
14 toyota          70    70
15 volkswagen      75    75
```