# How to reduce factor levels depending on other attribute?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of two columns `id` and `result`, and I want to assign factor levels to result depending on `id`. So that for id `"1"`, result `c("a","b","c","d")` will have factor levels 1,2,3,4. 
For id `"2"`, result `c("22","23","24")` will have factor levels 1,2,3.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
result <- c("a","b","c","d","22","23","24")
```

I tried to group them by split, but they will be converted to a list instead of a data frame, which causes a length problem for modeling. Can you help please?

Comment: Assuming you have dataframe `df <- data.frame(id, result)`, using `dplyr`, you can do `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% mutate(row = row_number())`

Comment: @RonakShah I don't believe this is a dupe of that one, you will have to convert `df %>% etc %>% mutate(fac = factor(row)) %>% select(-row)`, where `etc` is your code.

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic Sure, feel free to reopen if you disagree.

Answer (score 2):

Though the question was closed as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame) by user [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah), I don't believe it is the same question.

After numbering the row by group the new column must be coerced to class `"factor"`.

```
library(dplyr)

id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
result <- c("a","b","c","d","22","23","24")

df <- data.frame(id, result)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(fac = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(fac = factor(fac))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#     id result fac  
#  <dbl> <fct>  <fct>
#1     1 a      1    
#2     1 b      2    
#3     1 c      3    
#4     1 d      4    
#5     2 22     1    
#6     2 23     2    
#7     2 24     3
```

**Edit.**

If there are repeated values in `result`, coerce `as.integer/factor` to get numbers, then coerce those numbers to factor.

```
id2 <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
result2 <- c("a","b","c","d","22", "22","23","24")

df2 <- data.frame(id = id2, result = result2)

df2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(fac = as.integer(factor(result))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(fac = factor(fac))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#     id result fac  
#  <dbl> <fct>  <fct>
#1     1 a      1    
#2     1 b      2    
#3     1 c      3    
#4     1 d      4    
#5     2 22     1    
#6     2 22     1    
#7     2 23     2    
#8     2 24     3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked :D How can I assign factor levels to unique values of result? For example if result<- "22",22",23","24". It should have factor levels 1,1,2,3 instead of 1,2,3,4

Comment: @y.eska This means that the new column will have for `id == 1, result == "a"` the same factor level (value) as `id == 2, result == "22"`.

Answer (score 0):

After grouping by `id`, we can use `match` with `unique` to assign unique number to each `result`. Using @Rui Barradas' dataframe `df2`

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(ans = match(result, unique(result))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(ans = factor(ans))

#     id result ans  
#  <dbl> <fct>  <fct>
#1     1 a      1    
#2     1 b      2    
#3     1 c      3    
#4     1 d      4    
#5     2 22     1    
#6     2 22     1    
#7     2 23     2    
#8     2 24     3
```