# Creating new id by group of two columns with possibility of the same values

Tags: r

I would appreciate some help I am stuck.
I would like to create a new id based on two columns where the last column can have the same value.
***I have to maintain the current order which is done by a third column ORDER.***

```
    df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,2,2,2),order=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3), 
value = c(999, 999, 999, 250, 250, 999,999,250,250,999))

   id order value
1   1     1   999
2   1     2   999
3   1     3   999
4   1     4   250
5   1     5   250
6   1     6   999
7   1     7   999
8   2     1   250
9   2     2   250
10  2     3   999
```

I would like to have

```
      id value counter
 1     1   999       1
 2     1   999       1
 3     1   999       1
 4     1   250       2
 5     1   250       2
 6     1   999       3
 7     1   999       3
 8     2   250       4
 9     2   250       4
10     2   999       5
```

Every bit of code I tried is grouping regardless of order.

Thanks

Comment: This question is asked a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAVEAT: The `rle()` solution assumes the data is ordered.

---

Using `rle()`:

```
df$counter <- with(rle(with(df, paste(id, value))), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))
```

Adding pipes for readability:

```
library(magrittr)
df$counter <- df %>% 
  {paste(.$id, .$value)} %>% 
  rle() %>% 
  with(rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))
```

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df$counter <- with(df, rleid(id, value))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use base option with rle().

Comment: Data is ordered.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a run-length type id column. Try this

```
df$counter <- data.table::rleidv(df[, c("id", "value")])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```r
df$counter <- cumsum(!c(FALSE, 
                apply(head(df[c(1, 3)], -1) == tail(df[c(1, 3)], -1), 1, all)))

df[-2]
#>    id month counter
#> 1   1   999       1
#> 2   1   999       1
#> 3   1   999       1
#> 4   1   250       2
#> 5   1   250       2
#> 6   1   999       3
#> 7   1   999       3
#> 8   2   250       4
#> 9   2   250       4
#> 10  2   999       5
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this with a loop:

```
#Loop
df$Var <- NA
df$Var[1] <- 1
for(i in 2:nrow(df))
{
  df$Var[i] <- ifelse(df$month[i]==df$month[i-1],df$Var[i-1],df$Var[i-1]+1)
}
```

Output:

```
df
   id order month Var
1   1     1   999   1
2   1     2   999   1
3   1     3   999   1
4   1     4   250   2
5   1     5   250   2
6   1     6   999   3
7   1     7   999   3
8   2     1   250   4
9   2     2   250   4
10  2     3   999   5
```