# How to replace duplicate row values by appending indexes in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to replace duplicate row values in a given column by appending an underscore with an index based on their incidence. For example

```
old_df_col new_df_col
object object_1
object object_2
object object_3
object object_4
```

Most other questions focus around deleting or replacing duplicate values with NA so I wasn't able to find an implementation using `R` and `dplyr`.

Here's what I've worked out so far

```
# count duplicates
mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarize(n=n())

# filter duplicates
mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% filter(n()>1)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by the target variable and use `row_number()` to create the sequence.

Clearly, you might have to sort the data set previously (using `arrange()`) so that the sequence has some meaning for your data, but is not strictly necessary.

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% 
  arrange(carb, cyl, mpg, hp) %>% 
  mutate(
    carb_seq = paste("carb", carb, "seq", row_number(), sep = "_")
  )
# A tibble: 32 x 12
# Groups:   carb [6]
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb carb_seq    
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
 1  21.5     4 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1 carb_1_seq_1
 2  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 carb_1_seq_2
 3  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1 carb_1_seq_3
 4  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1 carb_1_seq_4
 5  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1 carb_1_seq_5
 6  18.1     6 225     105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1 carb_1_seq_6
 7  21.4     6 258     110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 carb_1_seq_7
 8  21.4     4 121     109  4.11  2.78  18.6     1     1     4     2 carb_2_seq_1
 9  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2 carb_2_seq_2
10  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2 carb_2_seq_3
# … with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>