# Count events in R per row depending on data range

Tags: r, dplyr, count, time-series

I have a dataset of 1000 patients (Patient 1-1000) undergoing the same type of procedure but by diffrent surgeons. I am interested to count the number of operations performed by each surgeon from study start date 27/06/2023 (for example) before the next procedure and insert this count/number per each patient/row. For example I need to know how many operations surgeon A performed on previous patients (1 and 2) before operating on patient 3 (e.g. 2 operation).Same for surgeon B etc.

I gues there is some formula in dplyr but I cannot get my head around it.

[image: Image of dataset and what I need to get]

```
Patient Surgeon Operation Date  Event before index (operation date)
1   A   28/06/2023  0
2   A   29/06/2023  1
3   A   30/06/2023  2
4   B   1/07/2023   0
5   C   2/07/2023   1
6   C   3/07/2023   2
```

Comment: Hi Daniel! What does your starting dataset look like? Please read the following post to make your question reproducible and get better, faster help: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: This existing question covers a number of possible methods to perform this general concept: [Numbering rows within groups in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame) The only difference for your case is you'll need to subtract 1 from your "counter" column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try the below code which can be give the `Event before index (operation date)` even if the patient is repeated operated by surgeon previously
please check the `new` variable

however at some places it does not match i.e., highlighted with `#`

```r
library(dplyr)

df_2 <- df %>% group_by(Surgeon,Patient) %>% 
  slice_tail(n=1) %>% group_by(Surgeon) %>% mutate(new=row_number()-1)

df_or <- df %>% 
  left_join(df_2 %>% select(Patient, Surgeon, new), by=c('Surgeon','Patient')) 


# output

# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Patient Surgeon Operation_Date Event_before   new
    <dbl> <chr>   <date>                <dbl> <dbl>
1       1 A       2023-06-28                0     0
2       2 A       2023-06-29                1     1
3       3 A       2023-06-30                2     2
4       4 B       2023-07-01                0     0
5       5 C       2023-07-02                1     0 #
6       6 C       2023-07-03                2     1 #
```

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to reply. I will check the codes and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Thank you @DanielFudulu for the confirmation and choosing it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your desired result is the row number for each surgeon minus one.

```
library(dplyr)

your_data |>
  mutate(event_before_index = row_number() - 1, .by = Surgeon)
```

This assumes your data is already sorted by date. If not, you can convert your date column to a proper `Date` class and sort it before running the above command.

```
library(lubridate)
your_data |>
  mutate(Operation_Date = dmy(Operation_Date)) |>
  arrange(Surgeon, Operation_Date) |>
  mutate(event_before_index = row_number() - 1, .by = Surgeon)
```