# How to count cumulative appearances in previous observations in R using tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr

**Data**

```r
d <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19649, 19653, 19654, 19655, 
19654, 19655, 19653, 19654, 19655, 19643, 19654, 19649, 19650, 
19654, 19649, 19653, 19636, 19640, 19646, 19647, 19653, 19649, 
19650, 19653, 19654, 19655), class = "Date"), id = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-26L), class = "data.frame")

print(d)
```

```
         date id
1  2023-10-19  1
2  2023-10-23  1
3  2023-10-24  2
4  2023-10-25  2
5  2023-10-24  3
6  2023-10-25  3
7  2023-10-23  4
8  2023-10-24  4
9  2023-10-25  4
10 2023-10-13  5
11 2023-10-24  6
12 2023-10-19  7
13 2023-10-20  7
14 2023-10-24  8
15 2023-10-19  9
16 2023-10-23  9
17 2023-10-06 10
18 2023-10-10 10
19 2023-10-16 11
20 2023-10-17 11
21 2023-10-23 11
22 2023-10-19 12
23 2023-10-20 12
24 2023-10-23 12
25 2023-10-24 13
26 2023-10-25 14
```

I want to count the cumulative number of appearances of each ID by date. For example:

```
        date id count
1  2023-10-19  1     1
2  2023-10-23  1     2
3  2023-10-24  2     1
4  2023-10-25  2     2
5  2023-10-24  3     1
6  2023-10-25  3     2
7  2023-10-23  4     1
8  2023-10-24  4     2
9  2023-10-25  4     3
10 2023-10-13  5     1
11 2023-10-24  6     1
12 2023-10-19  7     1
13 2023-10-20  7     2
14 2023-10-24  8     1
15 2023-10-19  9     1
16 2023-10-23  9     2
17 2023-10-06 10     1
18 2023-10-10 10     2
19 2023-10-16 11     1
20 2023-10-17 11     2
21 2023-10-23 11     3
22 2023-10-19 12     1
23 2023-10-20 12     2
24 2023-10-23 12     3
25 2023-10-24 13     1
26 2023-10-25 14     1
```

Is there a way to do this with dplyr/the tidyverse?

Comment: I think this is just a row counter per `id` group: `d %>% mutate(count = row_number(), .by=id)` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

Using summarize and mutate:

```r
library(dplyr)
d |> 
  group_by(date) |> 
  reframe(id = unique(id)) |> 
  group_by(date, id) |> 
  count() |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(count = cumsum(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77363184/how-to-count-cumulative-appearances-in-previous-observations-in-r-using-tidyvers/77363480#comment136386273_77363184):

```
dplyr::mutate(d, count = row_number(), .by = id)
```